# Get the uri of the page in Google App Engine / Django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest

I'm using Google App Engine with the standard Django templates found in Webapp.

I wanted to display the permalink to the page the user is on.  How do I get the uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be in `self.request.url` in your `RequestHandler`-based class.